# How to pass a parameter to a subscribe function used to get the content of an assets file in typescript/ionic 3?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I know I can get the content of a text file inside my assets directory in typescript like

```
this.http.get('assets/data/file_1.txt')
.subscribe(data=>{
   let obj = data['_body'];
   console.log("obj "+JSON.stringify(obj)); // This log the content of the file
});
```

It is possible to pass a parameter/value to this request?

I mean, in my case i have several file (file_4.txt,file_5.txt,file_1.txt) and I want to repeat the request for any of them (number and indexes could be variable in time). So my code sounds like

```
var fileIndex=[4,5,1]; 
for (i = 0; i < this.fileIndex.length; i++) { 
  this.http.get('assets/data/file_'+this.fileIndex[i]+'.txt')
  .subscribe(data=>{
        let obj = data['_body'];
        console.log("obj "+JSON.stringify(obj));
        console.log("This is file number "+this.fileIndex[i]); // problem is here
      });
}
```

I can't log what the file number is for any of the three requests generated this way.

Logging this.fileIndex[i] inside subscribe returns "undefined" and I can imagine why. The get request is asynchronous and can't access the values of i. Maybe also of fileIndex, isn't?

So, I can pass a parameter/value to the request so that I can get it inside the subscribe? Or, anyway, how may I can access the this.fileIndex[i] value inside the subscribe function?

Answer (score 0):

One solution, considering that in data['url'] there is the full url of the request, is

```
var fileIndex=[4,5,1]; 
for (i = 0; i < this.fileIndex.length; i++) { 
  this.http.get('assets/data/file_'+this.fileIndex[i]+'.txt,' {
        params: { fileNumber: this.fileIndex[i] }
    }).subscribe(data=>{
        let obj = data['_body'];
        console.log("obj "+JSON.stringify(obj));
        console.log("This is file number "+
this.getQueryString("fileNumber",data['url']));
      });
}

getQueryString = function ( field, url ) {
    var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
    var reg = new RegExp( '[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i' );
    var string = reg.exec(href);
    return string ? string[1] : null;
  };
```

but doesn't seems quite elegant.